# what is same c# code in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, cookies

```
 HttpCookie newCookie = Request.Cookies["cookie1"]; 
 int count = (newCookie .Values.Keys.Count) / 6;
 int keyCount = (newCookie .Values.Keys.Count);
 string val = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(newCookie .Values.GetKey(i).ToString());
 string str = newCookie .Values.GetKey(i).ToString();

 // i is loop counter
```

i want use javascript cookie, is there any way to use same code in javascript from above C# code?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp look to this

Comment: You want to implement these in server side or client side?

Comment: client side with JS...

Answer (score 0):

Try Like

```
 Set Cookie : document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
 Get Cookie : vat x = document.cookie ;
```